# rm -i alias not working with sudo as root

Tags: sudo, root, rm

I have noticed in all my Ubuntu servers the alias `rm -i` is ignored when you run `sudo rm *` as root.  Is there something in sudo that is causing this behavior? I know you don't need to use sudo when you are root however in the event that a Jr SA were to do so it would remove the contents of the directory.  Also knowing that `rm` in Ubuntu does not preserve / it could mean a total system meltdown.

Example as root:

```
johndoe@hostname:/tmp/foobar $ sudo su -
root@www3d:~# cd /tmp/foobar
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# for i in 'a b c d e f g' ; do touch $i ; done
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# sudo rm *
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# for i in 'a b c d e f g' ; do touch $i ; done
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `c'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `d'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `e'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `f'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `g'? y
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# for i in 'a b c' ; do touch $i ; done
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `c'? y
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# for i in 'a b c' ; do touch $i ; done
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# sudo rm *
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# ls
root@hostname:/tmp/foobar# exit
logout
```

Example as user:

```
johndoe@hostname:/tmp/foobar $ for i in 'a b c' ; do touch $i ; done
johndoe@hostname:/tmp/foobar $ rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `c'? y
johndoe@hostname:/tmp/foobar $ for i in 'a b c' ; do touch $i ; done
johndoe@hostname:/tmp/foobar $ sudo rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `c'? y
```

Comment: FYI, this alias seems like terrible practice. If you ever use `rm` when you expect the alias to be there, you could have a "total system meltdown". I recommend you change the alias name to `rmi`. That way you'll never use regular rm by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very neat trick to solve this problem. Use the alias for sudo as follow.

```
alias sudo="sudo "
#Trailing space at the end.
```

Reason from the credit page at the end of post:

> A trailing space in value causes the next word to be checked for alias
>   substitution when the alias is expanded

.

**Example**

```
user@user-desktop:~/test$ for i in 'a b c d e f g' ; do touch $i ; done
(reverse-i-search)`al': un^Cias -a
user@user-desktop:~/test$ alias rm="rm -i"
user@user-desktop:~/test$ rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
r    m: remove regular empty file `c'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `d'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `e'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `f'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `g'? y
user@user-desktop:~/test$ for i in 'a b c d e f g' ; do touch $i ; done
user@user-desktop:~/test$ alias sudo='sudo '
user@user-desktop:~/test$ sudo rm *
rm: remove regular empty file `a'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `b'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `c'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `d'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `e'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `f'? y
rm: remove regular empty file `g'? y
```

Credits: [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo#Passing_aliases)

Comment: Thanks the alias for sudo did it.  I put it in the .bash_aliases.

Comment: Great, we need both "alias sudo='sudo '" and "alias rm='rm -i'"

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the `sudo` manual, I see the following:

```
   -i [command]
               The -i (simulate initial login) option runs the shell
               specified in the passwd(5) entry of the target user as a
               login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files
               such as .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a
               command is specified, it is passed to the shell for
               execution.  Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed.
               sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory
               before running the shell.  It also initializes the
               environment, leaving DISPLAY and TERM unchanged, setting
               HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH, as well as the
               contents of /etc/environment on Linux and AIX systems.  All
               other environment variables are removed.
```

That is, you don't get the environment variables from your `.bashrc` file (where the alias definitions from `.bash_aliases` are executed) unless you use `-i`.