# alias or nano -B not working using sudo

Tags: sudo, bashrc, alias

I have an alias set up

```
alias nano='nano -B'
```

in order to always make backups on change of files.

I did this in both `/home/<USER>/.bashrc` and in `/root/.bashrc`.

It works if I use

```
nano someFile
```

either as `<USER>` or `root`.

But when I use

```
sudo nano someFile
```

as `<USER>` backups are not made. (I'ld expect to find `someFiles~` in the same folder)

Is there an additional `.bashrc` or something for `sudo` where I have to add this `alias`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rm -i alias not working with sudo as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84366/rm-i-alias-not-working-with-sudo-as-root)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/22037/aliases-not-available-when-using-sudo

Comment: Your user ID's aliases are not used via sudo ; You may or may not want to use the trick in the previous comments. There might be reasons to have no aliases or other aliases for `root`.

Comment: Yes but I thought those other aliases would be defined in `/root/.bashrc`

Comment: Yes, and they are used if you run `sudo -i` (and get the root prompt).

Comment: @sudodus I usually used `sudo -i` pressed `Enter` and did my stuff (e.g. `nano ./.configFile`) as root. Now that you mention it I tried to do just `sudo -i nano /root/.configFile` which works fine , too. Is it a good Idea than to use an alias as `alias sudo='sudo -i'` or speaks anything against this?

Answer (score 1):

### Your user ID's aliases are not used via `sudo`

- You may or may not want to use the trick linked to in the comments.
- There might be reasons to have no aliases or other aliases for `root`.

  These aliases can be stored in `/root/.bashrc` as you already know. They can be used when you run interactively at the root prompt `#` after

  ```
    sudo -i  # activates root's aliases
  ```

but they are not activated when followed by the alias on the command line

```
    sudo -i <specific alias>  # does not activate root's aliases
    sudo -H <specific alias>  # does not activate root's aliases
```

**Examples:**

```
$ LANG=C sudo -i

root@xenial32:~# alias
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'

root@xenial32:~# grep -e ^alias -e \ alias /root/.bashrc
# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Using one of `root`'s aliases

```
root@xenial32:~# l
bin@  extractor.log  logfile.tar  mkusb.log

root@xenial32:~# exit
logout

sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ LANG=C sudo -i l
-bash: l: command not found

[127] sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ LANG=C sudo -H l
sudo: l: command not found

[1] sudodus@xenial32 ~ $ LANG=C sudo -i alias
sudodus@xenial32 ~ $
```

### I would not use `alias sudo='sudo -i'` because

- there is a risk, that you forget that you have superuser privileges, and may do things that you should only do with regular privileges. In other words, I would say that it defeats the purpose of `sudo` to always go to root prompt
- an alias does not work anyway on the command line with `sudo -i <specific alias>`
- it is often efficient to use `sudo` with the standard settings for text mode commands
- for GUI commands I would recommend `sudo -H` or `gksudo`